# Osiset\ShopifyApp\Exceptions\MissingShopDomainException

Tags: laravel, shopify, shopify-app, laravel-8, shopify-activemerchant

I am using a library ( https://github.com/osiset/laravel-shopify
) to create Shopify APP using Laravel. Everything is working fine. But facing the error in case of not logged in to Shopify App admin.I am beginner to Shopify and created custom app. Please guide.

[image]

Comment: please don't post pictures unless totally necessary.

Comment: Imagine to complain on SO to feel better about yourself when someone puts some more effort into asking questions, smh

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. I solved it by specifying my shop-url in the url parameters:

`https://example.com/?shop=myshop.myshopify.com`

This works also with ngrok:

`https://6a8b17b2c39a.ngrok.io/?shop=myshop.myshopify.com`

Answer (score 0):

Are you on local?

The AuthShop was changed back in v10 which now throws the exception above.

On production, it will redirect to /login. also check App_debug

Comment: No i am not in local i am on dev server.